# How to detect if logon screen or UAC is active

Tags: windows, authentication, uac

I want to find a way to detect if logon screen or UAC is active within my service process. For example:

1. the screen on which a user needs to choose account and type in password to log on.
2. the screen on which a user needs to type in password after screensaver (locked screen?).
3. when a UAC pops up.

Right now I look through the session 1 and examine all the processes, if I could find logonui.exe, I thought either of the first two scenarios should happen. But in fact, this method can only detect 
scenario 1.

[winlogon.exe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winlogon) still exists after logon screen. So I can't use winlogon.exe as a search target.

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms682573(v=vs.85).aspx) link, I think if I can find the current active (input) desktop name, default, screensaver or winlogon, I would be able to solve my question. So I followed [swatkat's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260878/openinputdesktop-to-determine-secure-login-desktop) answer, and my code is like this

```
HWINSTA hs = GetProcessWindowStation();
HWINSTA hwinsta = OpenWindowStation("winsta0", FALSE, READ_CONTROL | WRITE_DAC);
SetProcessWindowStation(hwinsta);

HDESK hd = OpenInputDesktop(0, TRUE, GENERIC_READ | DESKTOP_READOBJECTS);
if (hd != NULL) {
    DWORD size;
    GetUserObjectInformation(hd, UOI_NAME, NULL, 0, &size);
    TCHAR* name = (TCHAR*)alloca(size + sizeof(TCHAR));
    GetUserObjectInformation(hd, UOI_NAME, name, size, &size);
    CString result(name);
    LOG((CLOG_DEBUG "input desktop name: %s %d", result.c_str(), size));
    CloseDesktop(hd);
}
else {
    LOG((CLOG_DEBUG "failed to call OpenInputDesktop"));
}

CloseWindowStation(hwinsta);
SetProcessWindowStation(hs);
```

This seems to always return "default" no matter which screen it's on.

I'm not really familiar with windows desktop and station, so if I did something wrong please let me know.

Thanks in advance.
Jerry

Comment: Try `OpenInputDesktop` followed by `GetUserObjectInformation` with `UOI_NAME`.

Comment: @HarryJohnston it always returns "Default" as the desktop's name. I wonder if I should check some information from workstation?

Comment: @HarryJohnston sorry I forgot to mention I want to detect this in my service process

Comment: @Jerry a service always runs in the system session. The session has no desktop/UI interface. You will probably need to impersonate the logged on user and run a client application that communicates back to the service.

Comment: @RedSerpent do you mean using SetProcessWindowStation to set my service to the interactive station can't tell me which screen I'm currently on? It has to be called from a process within the same session and communicates back to service.

Comment: You can't use `SetProcessWindowStation` from a service to connect to the actual interactive station, because it is in a different Remote Desktop session.  You'll have to launch a process in the user's session.  WTSQueryUserToken is your friend here, though it will only work if you are running as local system.